# Send data from Node.js to Python while Python Code already running

Tags: python, node.js

I'm building an Electron app that requires some python backend. I'd like to not have to run the Python script every time I need to call data, as the file takes a while to get started (importing data and libraries), but the functionality is super fast.

I'm trying to find a way to send data from the .js-file to the Python file after the python script is initialised, but I don't seem to get it just right.

**main.js**

```
const spawn = require("child_process").spawn;
const pythonProcess = spawn('python',["hello.py"]);
pythonProcess.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
    alert(data)
});
pythonProcess.send(2)
```

**hello.py**

```
import sys
import time

for line in sys.argv:
    print(line)
```

This returns "[Hello.py, 1]" in the application, which are the initial arguments sent from the .js-file to the .py-file. The .js-file doesn't seem to execute the last line; pythonProcess.send().

How does one do this most easily? The idea is to detect sys.argv changes and run a function in the python file when so happens.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to pipe `node`'s stdout to `python`'s stdin and keep reading `stdin` in Python until it is over. What is not good is that you most probably want to have some console output from Node application, and you definately dont want it to be passed to Python.

Second, recommended approach is to use `tcp/ip` channel. In this case you also benefit from being able to move Python app to another machine/container. Listening tcp/ip input in Python is very simple, I usually use following approach:

```
from twisted.internet.protocol import Factory, Protocol
from twisted.protocols.basic import LineReceiver

class DataProcessor(LineReceiver):
  def lineReceived(self, line):
    print('Line received: {}'.format(line))

Factory factory = Factory()
factory.protocol = DataProcessor
reactor.listenTCP(8080, factory)
```

Answer (score -1):

All you need is to make an ajax request to your pythoncode. You can do this with jquery http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/, or use just javascript

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "~/pythoncode.py",
  data: { param: text}
}).done(function( o ) {
   // do something
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Could you explain what happens here? I'm not familiar with AJAX enough. Is this equivalent to the initialization, and then the later sends go into the function part? And what should I do on the python file side?

Comment: Heres a tutorial on how to implement it. Basically you have to setup a flask app and send request to python flask app through any http module from nodejs https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/python-javascript-communicate-json/